# Send form data from React to ASP.NET Core API

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, fetch-api

I editted the whole question because it was very long and confusing.

## Clear, concise new question

I was sending all data from my forms as a stringified JSON, but now I need to append a file, so I can no longer do this. How do I send my form data from React to an ASP.NET Core API in a format that allows appending files?

## Old question

I have several forms working perfectly: I send the data using fetch from React and receive it correctly as body in my ASP.NET Core API.

However, I need to send files now, and I don't know how to append them since I am just sending all of my content in a strinfified JSON.

```
fetch("localhost/api/test", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(body)
}).then(result => result.json()).then(
    (result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

I tried sending a FormData object built like this instead of the `JSON.stringify(body)`.

```
let formData = new FormData();
for (var property in body) {
    formData.append(property, body[property]);
}
```

But when I send this object instead of the stringified JSON I always get null for all the values in ASP.NET Core.

I also tried sending this:

```
URLSearchParams(data)
```

And this:

```
let formBody = [];
for (var property in details) {
    var encodedKey = encodeURIComponent(property);
    var encodedValue = encodeURIComponent(details[property]);
    formBody.push(encodedKey + "=" + encodedValue);
}
formBody = formBody.join("&");
```

And I tried different combinations of headers with every type of data encoding:

- No headers
- `'Content-Type': 'multipart/formdata'`
- `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`
- `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'`

I also tried getting the data from ASP.NET with both `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]`.

I think I have tried every possible combination of all the options I have explained above, with no result. I always get null values in my API.

***Edit:***

Right now, I am not even trying to send a file. I am trying to successfully send common data in the proper format before trying to attach a file. I don't know if I should change the title of the question.

This is my API code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("login")]
public object Login([FromBody] Credentials cred)
{
    // check credentials
    return CustomResult.Ok;
}
```

The class `Credentials`:

```
public class Credentials
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

The object `body` from React looks like this:

```
{
    username: "user",
    password: "pass"
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your `API` and `React` code for how you are uploading the image file? So that it can be resolved easily.

Comment: I don't even have a file input. I am just trying to send my data in a different way because I cannot send files over a stringified JSON, or can I?

Comment: You have two ways, Either `IFormFile Image` or image as `base64` where the image will be served as `string`

Comment: It took me quite some time to work this through myself. Remove any uncertainty as to whether its front end or back end by using Postman. You can craft the request using form-data etc and then ensure the api is working. Once that is fine use the debugging tools on the browser to see what request your client code is producing.

Comment: @NAJ To use postman was the best option. Backend was fine, the problem was the `for` loop I was using to append the values to the formData. I checked the object after the loop and it seemed ok but I decided to try change it to `Object.keys(data).forEach` and it worked. I still don't understand why but it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My whole question was a mess and, in my case, the problem was the `for` loop. However, I will try to explain clearly what I needed because there is a lot of missleading information online about how to submit a form to an API with React.

## Solution

### Backend

In the backend, accept POST petitions and get the data with `FromForm`. If you need to use credentials, it is probably better to pass them through headers instead of putting them as hidden inputs inside every single form.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public object Test([FromHeader] string token, [FromForm] MyDataClass data)
{
    // check token
    // do something with data
    return CustomResult.Ok;
}
```

If you bind an object, the properties **must have the same name** as the ones you are sending from the frontend and **must have a public setter**.

```
public class MyDataClass
{
    public string SomeInfo { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherInfo { get; set; }
}
```

### Frontend

Send the data as `FormData`. To do this, you can follow [this tutorial](https://mattboldt.com/2020/05/02/formdata-with-react-hooks-and-fetch/). That way, you won't need to worry about handling input changes and formatting your data before submitting it.

However, if your data is already in a plain JavaScript object, you can transform it in a `FormData` as shown below.

```
let formData = new FormData();
Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) {
    formData.append(key, data[key]);
});
```

Nonetheless, this is very basic and if you have a complex object (with arrays, nested objects, etc) you will need to handle it differently.

Finally, I used `fetch` to call my API. If you use it, it is important to **NOT set the `Content-Type` header**, because you will be overwritting the one that `fetch` automatically chooses for you, which will be the right one in most cases.

```
fetch("localhost/api/test", {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Token': "dummy-token"
        // DON'T overwrite Content-Type header
    },
    body: formData
}).then(result => result.json()).then(
    (result) => {
        console.log(result);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit more time now. (10 fish caught.)
I notice from your code you had used the header "multipart/formdata", It should have a hyphen; "multipart/form-data".

On my API I am specifying that it consumes the same type: `[Consumes("multipart/form-data")]`

I am not clear what the .net core defaults are and whether it should automatically de-serialise the form data but specifying it should rule out any ambiguity.

With my code I am sending a file with some parameters. On the api side it looks like:

```
    public class FileUpload_Single
    {
        public IFormFile DataFile { get; set; }
        public string Params { get; set; }
    }

    // POST: api/Company (Create New)
    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize(PermissionItem.SimulationData, PermissionAction.Post)]
    [RequestSizeLimit(1024L * 1024L * 1024L)]  // 1 Gb
    [RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L)] // 1 Gb
    [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
    public async virtual Task<IActionResult> Post([FromForm] FileUpload_Single data)
```

....
Then on the client side it looks like:

```
  let formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("DataFile", file);
  formData.append("Params", JSON.stringify(params));
  fetch(apicall, {
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      Authorization:
        "Bearer " + (localStorage.getItem("token") || "").replace(/['"]+/g, ""),
      Accept: "multipart/form-data",
    },
    body: formData,
  })
```

With the file coming from

```
  const changeHandler = (event) => {
    setSelectedFile(event.target.files[0]);
    setIsSelected(true);
  };
```

(from my React component)

Answer (score 0):

This work for my, thanks for det help NAJ,
///Client part////

```
uploadImage: (uploadImage: any): AppThunkAction<KnownAction> => (dispatch, getState) => {
        const appState = getState();
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('formFile', uploadImage);
        formData.append("fileName", uploadImage.name);
            fetch(`api/File/Upload`, {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: authHeader.authHeaderAddAccept(),
                body: formData
            })
                .then(response => response.json() as Promise<UploadFileResponse>)
                .then(data => {
                    console.log('UploadFiles');
                    console.info(data);
                    if (appState && appState.fileUpload) {
                        let selectedFileUpload: FilesUpload = { ...appState.fileUpload.selectedFileUpload };
                        selectedFileUpload.id = data.id;
                        selectedFileUpload.fileUrl = data.fileUrl;
                        selectedFileUpload.filePath = data.filePath;
                        selectedFileUpload.fileName = data.fileName;
                        dispatch({ type: 'SET_FILE_UPLOAD_ACTION', selectedFileUpload: selectedFileUpload });
                        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PDF_RECEIVE', enablePdf: false });
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        dispatch({ type: 'CREATE_PDF_REQUEST' });
    }
```

/////API Controller////

```
[HttpPost("Upload")]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
        [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
        [Consumes("multipart/form-data")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<UploadFileResponse>> UploadAsync([FromForm] UploadFileRequest uploadFileRequest)
        {
            try
            {
                UploadFileResponse uploadFileResponse = await _fileAgent.UploadAsync(uploadFileRequest);
                return Ok(uploadFileResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.