# Sending data through API to SQL Server database

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, sql-server

I checked the structure of the code with the API and database it looks correct however it states bad request when everything is right (400 Bad Request).

I am using react.js for front end, .NET for API and SQL Server for the database. After being able to post I will then implement download function as it will be implemented to open mobile phone file storage.

Front end (1) without JSON conversion:

```
const handleAddPFile = async () =\> {
try {

for (const row of rows) {
const { selectedCategory, selectedSubCategory, description, fileName, fileType, fileSize, hash } = row;
console.log("Values to be sent to the server:", {
selectedCategory,
selectedSubCategory,
description,
fileName,
fileType,
fileSize,
hash
});
// const hashByteArray = new TextEncoder().encode(hash);
// Upload file
const formDataForFileUpload = new FormData();

    // const formDataObject = {};
    // for (let pair of formDataForFileUpload.entries()) {
    //   formDataObject[pair[0]] = pair[1];
    // }
    // console.log("FormData:", formDataObject);

    // formDataForFileUpload.append('file', row.selectedFile);

    formDataForFileUpload.append("empId", "9999" );
    formDataForFileUpload.append("mainCategory", "test");
    formDataForFileUpload.append("category", selectedCategory);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("subCategory", selectedSubCategory);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("description", description);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("fileNAME", fileName);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("fileType", fileType);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("fileSize", fileSize);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("fileOBJ", hash);
    formDataForFileUpload.append("create_By", "dev");
    // console.log("Type of selectedCategory:", typeof selectedCategory);
    // console.log("Type of selectedSubCategory:", typeof selectedSubCategory);
    // console.log("Type of description:", typeof description);
    // console.log("Type of fileName:", typeof fileName);
    // console.log("Type of fileType:", typeof fileType);
    // console.log("Type of fileSize:", typeof fileSize);
    // console.log("Type of hash:", typeof hashByteArray);
    
    console.log("FormData:", Object.fromEntries(formDataForFileUpload));

    const responseForFileUpload = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3001/api/PFile/AddPFile",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formDataForFileUpload,
        headers: {
          // "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        }
      }
    );
    
    // Check the status of the response
    if (responseForFileUpload.ok) {
      // If the response status is within the 2xx range
      const result = await responseForFileUpload.json();
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      // If the response status is outside the 2xx range, handle the error
      console.error("Error:", responseForFileUpload.status, responseForFileUpload.statusText);
    }
  } // <-- Added a closing brace for the 'for' loop
} catch (error) {
  // Handle errors that occur within the try block
  console.error("Error:", error);
}
};
```

Front end (2) with JSON conversion:

```
   const handleAddPFile = async () => {
   try {
    for (const row of rows) {
        const { selectedCategory, selectedSubCategory, description, fileName, fileType, fileSize, hash } = row;

     console.log("Values to be sent to the server:", {
      selectedCategory,
      selectedSubCategory,
      description,
      fileName,
      fileType,
      fileSize,
      hash
    });

    // Create an object with the data
    const dataObject = {
      empId: "9999",
      mainCategory: "test",
      category: selectedCategory,
      subCategory: selectedSubCategory,
      description,
      fileNAME: fileName,
      fileType,
      fileSize,
      fileOBJ: hash,
      create_By: "dev",
    };

    // Convert the data object to JSON
    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(dataObject);

    // Create a FormData object for the file
    const formDataForFileUpload = new FormData();
    formDataForFileUpload.append("file", row.selectedFile);

    // Append the JSON data as a blob
    formDataForFileUpload.append("data", new Blob([jsonData], { type: "application/json" }));

    console.log("FormData:", formDataForFileUpload);

    const responseForFileUpload = await fetch(
      "http://localhost:3001/api/PFile/AddPFile",
      {
        method: "POST",
        body: formDataForFileUpload,
        // Don't set Content-Type for FormData, let the browser handle it
      }
    );

    // Check the status of the response
    if (responseForFileUpload.ok) {
      // If the response status is within the 2xx range
      const result = await responseForFileUpload.json();
      console.log(result);
    } else {
      // If the response status is outside the 2xx range, handle the error
      console.error("Error:", responseForFileUpload.status, responseForFileUpload.statusText);
    }
  } // <-- Added a closing brace for the 'for' loop
} catch (error) {
  // Handle errors that occur within the try block
  console.error("Error:", error);
}
};
```

API code which works using Swagger UI:

```
public class NewPFile
{
    public string empId { get; set; }
    public string mainCategory { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
    public string subCategory { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }    
    public string fileNAME { get; set; }
    public string fileType { get; set; }
    public string fileSize {  get; set; }
    public byte[] fileOBJ { get; set; }
    public string create_By { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("AddPFile")]
public IActionResult AddPFile([FromQuery] NewPFile newpfile) 
{
    try
    {
        string insertQuery = "INSERT INTO PFile_Submission (EMPID, MAINCATEGORY, CATEGORY, SUBCATEGORY, DESCRIPTION, FILENAME, FILETYPE, FILESIZE, FILEOBJ, ACTIVE, CREATE_BY, CREATE_DT) " +
                "VALUES (@empId, @mainCategory, @category, @subCategory, @description, @fileName, @fileType, @fileSize, @fileOBJ, 1, @create_By, @create_Dt);";

        string sqlDatasource = _configuration.GetConnectionString("DBApi");

        using (SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(sqlDatasource))
        {
            myCon.Open();

            using (SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, myCon))
            {
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@empId", newpfile.empId);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MainCategory", newpfile.mainCategory);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", newpfile.category);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@subCategory", newpfile.subCategory);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@description", newpfile.description);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileNAME", newpfile.fileNAME);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileType", newpfile.fileType);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileSize", newpfile.fileSize);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fileOBJ", newpfile.fileOBJ);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create_By", newpfile.create_By);
                insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@create_Dt", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"));

                // Add other parameters as needed for your new entry

                int rowsAffected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    return Ok("New entry added successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    return BadRequest("Failed to add new entry");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Log the exception or handle it accordingly
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        return StatusCode(500, $"Internal Server Error: {ex.Message}");
    }
}
```

I am expecting the code to be sent in the format the console log gave me in the front end.

```
category
:
"Application Form"
create_By
:
"dev"
description
:
"dddf"
empId
:
"9999"
fileNAME
:
"1.png"
fileOBJ
:
"88851de15ac649747e39e60360ea8e3726f3e5d0"
fileSize
:
"102466"
fileType
:
"image/png"
mainCategory
:
"test"
subCategory
:
"NA"
```

Comment: Looks like that API expects JSON, not an HTML form.

Comment: Do refer to the 2nd Front code which I recently added.

Comment: I used the one with JSON Conversion , no error from API but server not receiving data.

Comment: @Sim isnt [`[FromQuery]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.fromqueryattribute?view=aspnetcore-8.0) is for query string not `json`? though i do wonder why the react part had `formDataForFileUpload = new FormData()` which is for a form multipart format? it would be easier to just post it as a form, remove that `[FromQuery]` and make sure your submission mimetype is `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: I intend to add multiple upload and upload the various data of the file and the file itself as I intend to pull it back to download it.

Comment: this is the reponse from the api. {errors: {"": ["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]},…}
errors
: 
{"": ["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]}
""
: 
["Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."]
0
: 
"Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary."
status
: 
400
title
: 
"One or more validation errors occurred."
traceId
: 
"00-e9ec102d34045f9090dc23212aaf02e2-350fe19ad1dc359a-00"
type
: 
"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1"

Comment: In .NET create a new NewPFile object; serialize it to JSON.  That's what should be in your request body.

Comment: @BagusTesa my current code is currently pushing a an object however could it be that my server can't understand the response ?

Comment: *"pushing a an object"* - can you verify it on browser console's network tab? dont mix json and form submission, it will cause confusion for both your program and yourself.

Comment: @Sim look at [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72530184) for an example.

Comment: The HTTP 400 Bad Request error is the server saying it doesn't understand your client's request. Have you read through [Model Binding in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding) yet? It doesn't really make sense to use `[FromQuery]` on a route that's decorated with `[HttpPost]` and the client is sending all information in the HTTP Request's body.